# Todo el contenido de mi pagina dentro de un div

Tags: html, css

tengo una duda, es considerada una mala practica o afecta de alguna forma que todo mi sitio web este contenido dentro una etiqueta div? por citar un ejemplo de etiqueta,ya que estoy maquetando un pagina y sin darme cuenta coloque todo dentro de un div, el tema es que la pagina funciona correctamente, todo esta como yo quiero, pero tengo la duda de si es aconsejable.
Gracias.

Comment: Hola, tal vez podamos darte alguna indicación si subes el código del problema.

Comment: pasa que no es un problema de codigo, es solo saber si afecta de alguna forma o si es mala practica poner todo el contenido de mi pagina dentro un div general con por ejemplo clase container y listo.

Comment: me temo que si lo que buscas es opiniones no te podemos dar una respuesta, según [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) las preguntas basadas en opiniones son consideradas irrelevantes para el sitio.

Comment: aunque por otro lado te adelanto que no tendría por que afectar en ninguna forma, colocar todo el contenido HTML en un div no se considera mala practica ni nada por el estilo.

Comment: No tiene por qué afectar. Ahora bien, si vas a aplicar ciertos estilos CSS a bloques de tu página lo más simple es que dividas esos bloques en sus propios `div` dándoles un nombre de clase para aplicar los estilos. En realidad, casi todos los sitios web están dentro de un div grande que se llama `container` o `content` o como quieras y luego dentro hay otros `div` específicos. Otra cosa es la parte del `footer`, los encabezados, etc, eso deberías tenerlo bien definido, no mezclado. Ten en cuenta que a nivel de SE, si tienes la página mal ordenada puedes ser penalizado o tener desventajas.

Answer (score 0):

No es una mala práctica, sobretodo si usas `flexbox` y necesitas un `div` padre y otro `div` hijo. Un ejemplo de estos casos es:

```css
.padre {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.padre .hijo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="padre">
  <div class="hijo"></div>
</div>
```

### Conclusión:

No es mala práctica, tal como has visto en el ejemplo, pero no es que sea totalmente necesario para que tu web funcione.